# NSDate calling a method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nstimer

I'm new to coding, please forgive any ignorance!

background:

I have an app with a simple label that counts down to a given date in days, hours, minutes and seconds.
I did this using `NSDate` and `NSTimer`s:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Countdown timer
    destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1413961418];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)updateLabel {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    int units = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];

    [countdownLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%c : %ld%c : %ld%c : %ld%c", (long)[components day], 'd', (long)[components hour], 'h', (long)[components minute], 'm', (long)[components second], 's']];
}
```

Problem:

When the count down label reaches 0 (i.e. when we reach the given date) how can I get a method to fire such as hiding an object?

Comment: Side note - Why are you using `%c` for the `h`, `m`, etc. in your format string? Simply put the letters in the format string just like the colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to see if the current date is later than or equal to `destinationDate`.

```
if ([destinationDate timeIntervalSinceNow] <= 0) {
    // The destination date is in the past - do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i dont get your question, but could you verify if the label text is equal to something like "0:0:0 h.s"?

I mean, you already have the updateLabel method.

Comment: yes, the label is equal to the count down to the given date, so it says something like 180 days 10 hours 30 mins 2 seconds and then countdowns every second.

Answer (score 0):

If you want condition to check if countdown timer reaches to zero then try below condition:-

```
     if ([destinationDate compare:[NSDate 
    date]]==NSOrderedSame)

     //hiding your object
     }
```

Comment: This won't work. The dates are stored in milliseconds. The chances that the two are exactly equal is essentially zero.